# Variance - What is on the Vehicle and what the FSM states

Tags: honda, electrical, troubleshooting, accord, o2-sensor

2007 Honda Accord Manual Transmission

DTC indicated: P1157

Usual remedy is to replace the oxygen sensor

But I wanted to follow the diagnostic tree in the service manual until I discovered something strange: **ECU/PCM wire harness for Connector A and Connector B do not match colors in FSM**

So this is the problem:

A/F Sensor Connector Terminal Views match colors in FSM

ECU/PCM wire harness for Connector A and Connector B do not match colors in FSM

Which of the several (about 4 connectors in all) is Connector A or B? So I can positively identify ECM/PCM Terminal (A31)

[image: ECM A31 CONNECTOR PINOUT] 
[image: AIR FUEL RATION SENSOR PINOUT]

Comment: Ate you sure you have the correct manual / diagram for that specific model of car? There are usually multiple diagrams - manual, auto, 4cyl, v6 etc etc

Comment: My other thinking is *does it really matter*? Is the wiring working as specified? Do you have any inclination there was re-wire work done to the vehicle? If not, I'd bet it's just a variance where there's no real issue. Yes, confusing, but an issue? I'd bet not.

Comment: @SolarMike I think I did but I maybe wrong